# passing values in C++ - treat 1: exc bad access

Tags: c++, function

I have problems with following code:

```
void mc_duurtijd(int multiproject)
{
    double random_getal[MULTIPROJECT][PROJECTEN][ACTIVITEITEN][RUNS];
    double stochastische_duurtijd_berekenen[MULTIPROJECT][SCENARIO][PROJECTEN][ACTIVITEITEN][RUNS];

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);

    for (int p=0;p<PROJECTEN;p++)
    {
        for (int i=1;i<n_p[multiproject][p]-1;i++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < RUNS; r++)
            {
                random_getal[multiproject][p][i][r]=dis(gen);

            }
        }
    }

    for (int s=0;s<SCENARIO;s++)
    {
        for (int p=0;p<PROJECTEN;p++)
        {
            for (int i=1;i<n_p[multiproject][p]-1;i++)
            {
                for (int r=0;r<RUNS;r++)
                {
                    stochastische_duurtijd_berekenen[multiproject][s][p][i][r]=bepaal_stochatische_duurtijd(random_getal[multiproject][p][i][r],multiproject,s, p, i, r);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int s=0;s<SCENARIO;s++)
    {
        for (int p=0;p<PROJECTEN;p++)
        {
            for (int i=1;i<n_p[multiproject][p]-1;i++)
            {   stochastische_duurtijd[multiproject][s][p][i]=0.0;
                for (int r=0;r<RUNS;r++)
                {
                    stochastische_duurtijd[multiproject][s][p][i]+=stochastische_duurtijd_berekenen[multiproject][s][p][i][r];
                }
                stochastische_duurtijd[multiproject][s][p][i]=stochastische_duurtijd[multiproject][s][p][i]/RUNS;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int s=0;s<SCENARIO;s++)
    {
        for (int p=0;p<PROJECTEN;p++)
        {
            for (int i=1;i<n_p[multiproject][p]-1;i++)
            {
                stochastische_duurtijd[multiproject][s][p][i]=floor(stochastische_duurtijd[multiproject][s][p][i]/scale+0.5)*scale;
            }
        }
    }


void berekeningen_initieel(int multiproject) 
{
    mc_duurtijd(multiproject);                    
    bereken_CP_per_project_stochastisch(multiproject);
    bereken_CP_max_stochastisch(multiproject); 
    for (int s=0;s<SCENARIO;s++)              
    {
         bereken_backward_stochastisch(multiproject, s);
    }

    for (int s=0;s<SCENARIO;s++)               
    {
        bereken_slack_stochastisch(multiproject);
    }

    toekennen_activiteitID(multiproject);
}

int main()
{
    mp =0;

    scale=0.000000000001;

    srand(time(NULL)); //  the random seed is initialized to a value representing the current time (calling time) to generate a different value every time the program is run.

    inlezen_data();
    print_output();

    for (int multi =0; multi<MULTIPROJECT;multi++)
    {
        berekeningen_initieel(multi);
        maak_planning(multi);
        bereken_doelfunctie(multi);
        print_evaluatie(multi);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem starts when I try to run berekeningen_initieel(multi); So for the first iteration multi =0. I am passing this value into the function berekeningen_initieel(int multiproject). Here multiproject = 0 which is normal. But then I want to call the function mc_duurtijd (int multiproject). So I do this by doing mc_duurtijd(multiproject). Here the value of multiproject is equal to 0. but when I debug my code the function mc_duurtijd(int multiproject), here multiproject is NOT equal to zero but to 18455399351 (this all the time changes when I try to run my program). I really don't understand why the value 0 is not passing to the mc_duurtijd(int multiproject) function. Can someone help me?

Comment: Try to write the value to a log (or the console).

Comment: You need to do some debugging and narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all C execution environments use a stack to store local variables and return addresses from nested function calls. The size of the stack is usually configurable; typically it is capped at 1 MiB or so.

Given MULTIPROJECTEN = 420; PROJECTEN=3; ACTIVITEITEN=32; RUNS=100 *random_getal* in *mc_duurtijd* is approximately 32 MiB in size. Attempting to execute the program results in a stack overflow.

Use dynamic memory allocation (i.e. malloc) for large buffers.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @Nick, I also confirmed that this is most probably because of your array is too big for a function. But there is a workaround for this. You can move the array declaraation to outside function like this:

```
#define MULTIPROJECTEN  420 
#define SCENARIO          4
#define PROJECTEN         3
#define ACTIVITEITEN     32
#define RUNS            100

double random_getal[MULTIPROJECT][PROJECTEN][ACTIVITEITEN][RUNS];
double stochastische_duurtijd_berekenen[MULTIPROJECT][SCENARIO][PROJECTEN][ACTIVITEITEN][RUNS];

void mc_duurtijd(int multiproject) { ... }
void berekeningen_initieel(int multiproject) { ... }
int main() { ... }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion board. To perform iterative debugging with the OP, invite them to a chat room.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not able to run the function because the error xc_bad access occurs. Is it possible that this is due to the size and number of dimensions of my array? 
the array double random_getal[MULTIPROJECT][PROJECTEN][ACTIVITEITEN][RUNS]; with MULTIPROJECTEN = 420 ; PROJECTEN 3; ACTIVITEITEN= 32; RUNS = 100. When I reduce the size of the array by setting MULTIPROJECTEN = 5, it's working. But i really need such a high size..

Comment: I suspect `for (int i=1;i<n_p[multiproject][p]-1;i++)` is the bad part. Could you replace all of it occurrences with `for (int i=1;i<2;i++)` and see whether it is run without error?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit will do next time